# Prevent Chip component to send a REST request

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';

const styles = {
  root: {
    margin: 4,
  },
};

function CustomChipField({ root, classes, record, onClick }) {
  return (
    <Chip className={classes.root} label={`${record.name}`} onClick={onClick} />
  );
}

CustomChipField.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  record: PropTypes.shape({}),
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

CustomChipField.defaultProps = {
  record: {},
};

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomChipField);
```

What is it? It is a custom Chip component inheriting material-ui's chip.

But what I haven't figured out yet is why it sends REST request when I click it.
The example of such a request: `http://localhost:3000/#/users/{"name"3A"whatever_name"}`

I have an onClick prop overriden, and it was my attempt to override it but it doesn't do anything.

I use this component in the [SingleFieldList](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-singlefieldlist-component) of react-admin, and maybe the problem in react-admin but I use custom Chip component directly inherited from material-ui.

The code from react-admin:

```
export const UserList = props => (
  <List {...props}>
    <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
      <TextField source="id" />
      <TextField source="username" />
      <ArrayField source="some_array">
        <SingleFieldList>
          <CustomChipField
            source="name"
            size="small"
            clickable={true}
            onClick={handleClick}
          />
        </SingleFieldList>
      </ArrayField>
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

And once again - onClick prop doesn't work.

So the question is: how to whether prevent Chip component sending a REST-request, whether to customize it.

Comment: Seems like in the UserList you pass the onClick prop to the CustomChipField. I would imagine the request is done over there?

Comment: No. This was my attempt to override it. And it doesn't work. I will remove it from the code to prevent confusion.

Comment: @szczocik Edited it, now I mention onClick in the question, and it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<SingleFieldList linkType={false}>
   <CustomChipField />
</SingleFieldList>
```

Comment: This is indeed an answer. Found this like two to three weeks ago, but forgot to add an answer.  
Thank you.